# Voix passive d'une phrase négative

Tags: grammaire

J'aimerais savoir si on peut mettre cette phrase à la voix passive :

> Monsieur, je n'ai point l'honneur d'appartenir à votre classe.

Comment: Comme indiqué dans une réponse, on ne peut pas directement mettre cette phrase à la voix passive. On peut cependant utiliser des tournures du type *votre classe ne me fait pas l'honneur de me compter parmi ses membres*. Une tournure directe comme la vôtre me semble préférable.

Answer (score 4):

On ne peut mettre à la voix passive que les verbes transitifs à complément d'objet direct.

| Type de verbe | Active | Passive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Transitif | J'ai mangé la tarte. | La tarte a été mangée par moi. |
| Transitif | Tu as salué le public. | Le public a été salué par toi. |
| Intransitif | Elle a dormi. | ? |

Il y a deux verbes dans la phrase que vous avez citée : *avoir* et *appartenir*.

*Avoir* est un verbe transitif, tandis que *appartenir* ne l'est pas. Alors, on imagine qu'il est possible de dire « L'honneur n'est point eu par moi » mais pas « <strike>Votre classe est appartenue à par moi.</strike> »

Cela dit, même ce premier choix ne semble pas naturel à mon oreille. Bien que ce serait peut-être permis, j'ai l'impression que « avoir » dans le sens de « posséder » ne se soumet pas très facilement à ce type de transformation.

(Et pour être clair, la négation n'y a rien à voir. La passivité est indépendante de la négation.)

Comment: En adaptant un peu la phrase, on pourrait dire: *Appartenir à votre classe n'est pas un honneur dont je dispose.*

Comment: @jlliagre En effet. Il y a plusieurs alternatives à la passivité strictement grammaticale.